# Nesting labels in ResourceBundleMessageSource - possible?

Tags: spring, resourcebundle

I would like to achieve a following behaviour using [ResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html):

Having file below, I want to render `Dear Customer of MyCompany` message.

```
# messages.properties
company.name=MyCompany
welcomeMessage.beginning=Dear Customers of ${company.name}
```

Is it possible to nest in some way a key of one label in value of different one?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, resolving arbitrary objects is part of the MessageSource interface. So to resolve a plain message code you just need to enclose it in DefaultMessageSourceResolvable like:

```
messageSource.getMessage("welcomeMessage.beginning",
                         new Object[]{new  DefaultMessageSourceResolvable("company.name")},
                         locale);
```

You do not need fancy message format (nor you are allowed by standard MessageFormat), just use:

```
# messages.properties
company.name=MyCompany
welcomeMessage.beginning=Dear Customers of {0}
```